# Cursor offset in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: internet-explorer, focus, textarea, internet-explorer-11

I have a textarea that is hidden. When I show it and focus inside, the cursor is offset to the top in Internet Explorer 11. All other IE´s are fine. How do I fix this new and nasty bug and what causes it?

Html:

```
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
<button id="button">click me</button>
```

CSS:

```
#textarea {
  display: none;
}
```

JS/jQuery:

```
$("#button").on("click", function(){
   $("#textarea").show().focus()
})
```

[image]

Try code:
http://jsfiddle.net/fmea9/

Comment: Anyone could help with this? I'm having the same problem.... Tried setting timeout etc but no luck. The only time it would work if we don't use display `none`...

Answer (score 1):

Please try this solution:

CSS:

```
TEXTAREA[hidden]{
   display:none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<textarea hidden="hidden" id="txt1"></textarea>
```

JS:

```
$('#txt1').removeAttr('hidden').focus(); //to show element
$('#txt1').attr('hidden', 'hidden'); //to hide element
```